# How do you create a multipurpose launcher?

Tags: command-line

I want to create a single launcher for Chrome, Banshee,Thunderbird and Gwibber. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive, in the sense is it for natty launchers? Because in Unity, I know a way to have one launcher for chrome, banshee, thunderbird and gwibber by editing .desktop files.

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 10.10 and below**

Create a file that contains these commands:

```
!#/bin/sh
thunderbird &
gwibber-service &
banshee &
#chrome & # commented out, because I don't know the exact command.
# find out by typing "chrom" into terminal and autocomplete with tab
```

Save it e.g. as ~/ChromeBansheeThunderbirdGwibberStarter and assign execute-permission:

```
chmod +x ~/ChromeBansheeThunderbirdGwibberStarter
```

Now right-click panel, Add to panel..., Custom Application Launcher

```
Type: Application
Name: (whatever you like)
Command: ~/ChromeBansheeThunderbirdGwibberStart
```

Clicking the icon will allow you selecting something else for your launcher.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Worked like a charm. Cheers!

Comment: Would you mark my answer as solution, please? This would also remove your question from "unanswered" :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question "command-line" you might want to `man gnome-open`

Indeed I use this so often I have

```
alias go=gnome-open
```

in my `~/.bash_aliases` file.